# How to use third-party JavaScript libraries in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

How do you guys manage to use Laravel Mix if there are many third-party JavaScript plugins? I use Laravel Mix for normal things, but now I have an Admin Panel Dashboard theme, and there are lots of plugins used as follows.

```
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/detect.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/fastclick.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.blockUI.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/waves.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/wow.min.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js”></script>
<script src=“assets/js/jquery.app.js”></script>
```

These are the javascript files, and also there are CSS files for the same as well. So what is the best-recommended way to do it?

Comment: [Have you looked at the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#working-with-scripts)?  It is explained very clearly.

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic, thank you for your kind response, yes I've gone through it, but my question is there is a folder of plugin too, where around more than 20 plugins are added, so is there anything wrong if I add all those plugins in laravel mix? I'm sorry I'm looking for the best recommended method

Comment: @Siddharth did you find a solution on this?

Comment: I usually combine common scripts and styles (jquery, bootstrap, blockui, etc) in a "common.js" (or app.js) and "common.css" with laravel mix, and include them in the main layout. Other scripts and styles are put in subviews only when needed, using two sections inside the main layout.

Comment: if scripts are page specific you can use `@push` and `@stack` blade methods to include scripts and CSS. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks